# Is Mysql driver supports savepoints?

Tags: mysql

What is the mysql driver version that supports Savepoints. Currently I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InnoDB supports the SQL statements SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT. Starting from MySQL 5.0.3, RELEASE SAVEPOINT and the optional WORK keyword for ROLLBACK are supported as well.

To find more about mysql drivers refer the link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/savepoint.html